# jquery .next can't find sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't seem to get a prepended span to find its ul sibling within it's parent li...shouldn't it find it regardless if they're not the same tag?

here's the prepend, in the css it's floating to the right of the contents of the list item, but that shouldn't affect it right?

```
$('aside ul > li').prepend('<span class="icon-arrow-right"></span');
```

and here's the click function which doesn't seem to properly produce an alert:

```
$('aside .icon-arrow-right').click(function(){
        if($(this).next('ul').hasClass('sub-nav')) {
            alert('yes');
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }
    });
```

the current results of this function will always pop up a 'no' regardless if the list item has a child UL with the class sub-nav.

edit:  Here's the html, please note that the js adds the span, it's not natively there:

```
<ul>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Accommodations</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Inland View Rooms</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Partial Ocean View Rooms</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Harbor View Rooms</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Ocean View Rooms</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">ADA Accessible Guestroom</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Executive Suites</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Spa Terrace Suite</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Cannery Row Suite</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Grand Bay Suite</a></li>
        <li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="">Presidential Suite</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Destination</a></li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Dining</a></li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Spa</a></li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Meetings &amp; Events</a></li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Weddings</a></li>
<li><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
<li class="book-header"><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span><a href="#">Book Now</a></li>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like before you do the `prepend`?

Comment: Can you make a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've added the html of the UL list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.next()` method only returns the immediate next sibling of an element, and if it doesn't match the provided selector it returns nothing.

In your case the `.next()` element isn't a `<ul>`, it's the `<a>` element.

To find the first matching sibling, use `.nextAll('ul').first()`